# regex replace in middle

Tags: regex

I trying to replace string "Resources.AppResource.Info;" like this "Switch("Info");"  Is this possible with regex?

Comment: When you want an regular expression solution, you should first think about if a regular expression is really needed. If you have only one search&replace case, then regular expressions are not needed. If you have more cases, you should include some more, so the regularities between those cases can be seen correctly. As of now, there are too many different possibilites to match that single case, to give you a good answer.

Comment: @ring0: Why do you need the language? Regular expressions are completely language-independent, and providing a matching and replacing string should be enough to get it working.

Comment: That's not true. There are different syntaxes for the regexps (e.g. Emacs and Perl, PHP offers two different syntaxes with Perl-compatible and POSIX-extended etc... Also, when one want to help you and give you some hints with a sentence, she needs to know the language. Finally, I wanted to ensure the C# guess was exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this C#? If it is, then this would work:

```
Regex.Replace("Resources.AppResource.Info;", @"Resources\.AppResource\.(\w+);", @"Switch(""$1"")")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include the programming language you are working with. And I'm guessing its C#.

```
string info = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("Resources.AppResource.Info;", @"\w+\.\w+\.(\w+);", "Switch($1);");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing, a code example would really help, with input and expected output. How does the middle of the string help?

If I understand right you probably want a substitution of one string for another.

Here's some sed, something similar would work for vi and perl

```
s/Resources\.AppResource\.Info/Switch\("Info"\)\;/
```

This would work in ruby

```
app_string.gsub("Resources.AppResource.Info;",
                'Switch("Info")';
```